# margin: 0 auto; not centering when there is a width

Tags: html, css

So I was making different parts to go to a little mini "about me" page. And in all divs (this is the most relevant) I have widths and heights. And it will not let me do margin: 0 auto;.

```css
body {
background: #aaa;
}

#about {
font-family: arial;
width: 300px;
height: 20px;
text-align: center;
padding-left: 10px;
opacity: 0.5;
padding-top: 4px;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: #000;
position: fixed;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
font-size: 11px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
}

#about:hover {
height: 250px;
}

.about-text {
width: 300px;
height: 220px;
overflow-y: auto;
margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="about">
<font face="arial" color="#fff">&#120016;&#120043;&#120056;&#120062;&#120061; &#120028;&#119942;</font>

<div class="about-text">
<font face="arial" color="#fff"><br>
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.</font>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's because you have `position:fixed`.  Add something like this: `left:calc(50% - 150px);`

Comment: I also tried using position:absolute and no change was made. But what you suggested did work.

Answer (score 0):

The div is `position:fixed`.  That takes it `out of the flow`, so you need to give it a `left` (or `right`) - something like this:

```css
body {
background: #aaa;
}

#about {
font-family: arial;
width: 300px;
height: 20px;
text-align: center;
padding-left: 10px;
opacity: 0.5;
padding-top: 4px;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: #000;
position: fixed;
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
-webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
overflow: hidden;
font-size: 11px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
}

#about:hover {
height: 250px;
}

.about-text {
width: 300px;
height: 220px;
overflow-y: auto;
margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="about">
<font face="arial" color="#fff">&#120016;&#120043;&#120056;&#120062;&#120061; &#120028;&#119942;</font>

<div class="about-text">
<font face="arial" color="#fff"><br>
Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.</font>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encapsulate in a container div, I have been modified this. :)

```css
body {
background: #aaa;
}
.container{
width: 100%;
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
}
#about {
font-family: arial;
width: 300px;
height: 20px;
text-align: center;
padding-left: 10px;
opacity: 0.5;
padding-top: 4px;
border-radius: 10px;
background-color: #000;
position: relative;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
font-size: 11px;
-webkit-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
-moz-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
-o-transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
transition: all 0.8s ease-out;
}

#about:hover {
height: 250px;
}

.about-text {
width: 300px;
height: 220px;
overflow-y: auto;
margin-top: 5px;
}
```

```html
    <div class="container">
    <div id="about">
    <font face="arial" color="#fff">&#120016;&#120043;&#120056;&#120062;&#120061; &#120028;&#119942;</font>

    <div class="about-text">
    <font face="arial" color="#fff"><br>
    Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text. Text.</font>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```